# Akka-Streams ActorPublisher does not receive any Request messages

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to continuously read the wikipedia IRC channel using this lib: https://github.com/implydata/wikiticker

I created a custom Akka Publisher, which will be used in my system as a `Source`.

Here are some of my classes:

```
class IrcPublisher() extends ActorPublisher[String] {
  import scala.collection._

  var queue: mutable.Queue[String] = mutable.Queue()

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case Publish(s) =>
      println(s"->MSG, isActive = $isActive, totalDemand = $totalDemand")
      queue.enqueue(s)
      publishIfNeeded()

    case Request(cnt) =>
      println("Request: " + cnt)
      publishIfNeeded()

    case Cancel =>
      println("Cancel")
      context.stop(self)

    case _ =>
      println("Hm...")
  }

  def publishIfNeeded(): Unit = {
    while (queue.nonEmpty && isActive && totalDemand > 0) {
      println("onNext")
      onNext(queue.dequeue())
    }
  }
 }

object IrcPublisher {
  case class Publish(data: String)
}
```

I am creating all this objects like so:

```
  def createSource(wikipedias: Seq[String]) {
      val dataPublisherRef = system.actorOf(Props[IrcPublisher])
      val dataPublisher = ActorPublisher[String](dataPublisherRef)
      val listener = new MessageListener {
        override def process(message: Message) = {
          dataPublisherRef ! Publish(Jackson.generate(message.toMap))
        }
      }

      val ticker = new IrcTicker(
        "irc.wikimedia.org",
        "imply",
        wikipedias map (x => s"#$x.wikipedia"),
        Seq(listener)
      )

      ticker.start() // if I comment this...
      Thread.currentThread().join() //... and this I get Request(...)

      Source.fromPublisher(dataPublisher)
}
```

So the problem I am facing is this `Source` object. Although this implementation works well with other sources (for example from local file), the ActorPublisher don't receive `Request()` messages.

If I comment the two marked lines I can see, that my actor has received the Request(count) message from my flow. Otherwise all messages will be pushed into the queue, but not in my flow (so I can see the MSG messages printed).

I think it's something with multithreading/synchronization here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar enough with wikiticker to solve your problem as given.  One question I would have is: why is it necessary to join to the current thread?

However, I think you have overcomplicated the usage of [`Source`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/?_ga=1.232739871.129608303.1419543038#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source$).  It would be easier for you to work with the stream as a whole rather than create a custom `ActorPublisher`.

You can use `Source.actorRef` to materialize a stream into an ActorRef and work with that ActorRef.  This allows you to utilize akka code to do the enqueing/dequeing onto the buffer while you can focus on the "business logic".

Say, for example, your entire stream is only to filter lines above a certain length and print them to the console.  This could be accomplished with:

```
def dispatchIRCMessages(actorRef : ActorRef) = {
  val ticker = 
     new IrcTicker("irc.wikimedia.org",
                   "imply",
                   wikipedias map (x => s"#$x.wikipedia"),
                   Seq(new MessageListener {
                         override def process(message: Message) = 
                          actorRef ! Publish(Jackson.generate(message.toMap))
                       }))

  ticker.start()
  Thread.currentThread().join()
}


//these variables control the buffer behavior
val bufferSize = 1024
val overFlowStrategy = akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropHead

val minMessageSize = 32

//no need for a custom Publisher/Queue
val streamRef = 
  Source.actorRef[String](bufferSize, overFlowStrategy)
        .via(Flow[String].filter(_.size > minMessageSize))
        .to(Sink.foreach[String](println))
        .run()

dispatchIRCMessages(streamRef)
```

The `dispatchIRCMessages` has the added benefit that it will work with any `ActorRef` so you aren't required to only work with streams/publishers.

Hopefully this solves your underlying problem...

Comment: I have to wait on the ticker thread (the join call) because ticker needs some time to init properly. In my experiments, if I do not join the threads I will get some IO-Exceptions (InterruptedException) from the ticker. So, I think it is because some background thread work from Akka.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is `Thread.currentThread().join()`. This line will 'hang' current thread because this thread is waiting for himself to die. Please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long- .